# how can i use less &:global(.static_classname) in scss

Tags: sass, less, css-modules, scss-mixins

less file

```
.design {
  &:global(.ant-input-number) {
    color: #2a2f3c;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: DIN Alternate, serif;
    line-height: 16px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(188, 193, 205, 0.5);
    border-radius: 4px;
  }
}
```

got css like this

```
.design___3dNL4.ant-input-number {
    color: #2a2f3c;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: DIN Alternate,serif;
    line-height: 16px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(188,193,205,.5);
    border-radius: 4px;
}
```

how can i get same effect in scss?

i tried

```
.customTabLayout:global(.ant-tabs-small){
   ...
}
```

antd this one

```
.customTabLayout{
  &:global(.ant-tabs-small){
    ...
  }
}
```

not working...
i may need some help, thanks

Answer (score 0):

right all that's way
i used wrong tag in my project file

```
.customTabLayout:global(.ant-tabs-small){
  background-color: red;
  :global{
    .ant-tabs-nav .ant-tabs-tab{
      padding: 8px 12px;
      border: 1px solid #cfcfe0;
      margin: 0;
      &+.ant-tabs-tab{
        border-left: 0;
      }
    }
  }
}
```